# Add a suffix to a new column

Tags: r, dplyr

Aim to create a new column named that contains the suffix '_left' after function "left" has been applied
New DF columns
Study
bd_acct
bd_acct_left
cc
cc_left

Rather than changing names manually I would like to find a way of automating this addition of a suffix

```
study <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
bd_acct <- c(57,66,72,24,76,98,56,32,43,250000,87,34,0,0,67)
cc <- c(1,2,3,5,74,3,5,6,5,3,5,6,7,4,1)
trial_A <- data.frame(study, bd_acct,cc) 

left <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) (quantile(x,0.25) - 1.5*IQR(x))
trial_A %>% mutate_at(c("bd_acct", "cc"), left)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dplyr::mutate` with `across()` and the `.names` argument:

```
library(dplyr)
trial_A %>% 
  mutate(across(bd_acct:cc, left, 
                .names = "{.col}_left"))
```

Output:

```
#    study bd_acct cc bd_acct_left cc_left
# 1      1      57  1        -28.5   -0.75
# 2      2      66  2        -28.5   -0.75
# 3      3      72  3        -28.5   -0.75
# .....
```